# Chaining lambda expressions in MVC.Net without repetitious passing of HtmlHelper object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, chaining

My goal is to create an object to allow chaining of commands in MVC.Net views.

Here is an example use in a view of a menu I created using this concept:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <%: Html
        .menu()
            .item("Introduction", "Introduction", "Home")
            .item("About", "About", "Home")
            .item("Systems", "Index", "Systems")
            /*.item("Categories", "Categories", "Health")*/
            .item("Test Cases", "TestCases", "Testing")
            .category("Logging")
                .item("UniMon Events", "UniMonEvents", "Logging")
            .end()
        .end() %>
</nav>
```

As you can see it allows for the quick construction of a multi-tiered menu with interdependencies between the various parts.

I would like to achieve this same effect for a form using lambda expressions.

The ideal syntax would look like this:

```
<%: Html
    .form()
        .hidden(m=>m.property1)
        .hidden(m=>m.property2)
    .end() %>
```

Where I am running into trouble is with the **hidden** method. It seems there is no way to get the compiler to infer **m** without passing it to the method **hidden**.

I can achieve this syntax:

```
<%: Html
    .form()
        .hidden(Html, m=>m.property1)
        .hidden(Html, m=>m.property2)
    .end() %>
```

Using this class and an extension method(not shown):

```
public class RouteForm
{
    public HtmlHelper HtmlHelper { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> PostData { get; private set; }

    public RouteForm(HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        HtmlHelper = htmlHelper;
        PostData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public RouteForm hidden<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string value = GetFieldValue(htmlHelper, expression);
        PostData.Add(name, value);
        return this;
    }
    private static string GetFieldValue<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        object oValue = expression.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
        string value = (oValue is Enum) ? ((int)oValue).ToString() : oValue.ToString();
        return value; ;
    }
    public MvcHtmlString end()
    {
        //TODO: render form with post data
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
}
```

I thought that perhaps a class with a generic type might be what I am looking for, so I tried this:

```
public class RouteForm<TModel>
{
    public HtmlHelper<TModel> HtmlHelper { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> PostData { get; private set; }

    public RouteForm(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)
    {
        HtmlHelper = htmlHelper;
        PostData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public RouteForm<TModel> hidden<TModel, TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string value = GetFieldValue(expression);
        PostData.Add(name, value);
        return this;//ERRORS: TModel is TModel
    }
    private string GetFieldValue<TModel, TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        object oValue = expression.Compile()(
            (TModel)HtmlHelper.ViewData.Model //ERRORS: Cannot convert type TModel to TModel
        );
        string value = (oValue is Enum) ? ((int)oValue).ToString() : oValue.ToString();
        return value; ;
    }
    public MvcHtmlString end()
    {
        //TODO: render form with post data
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
}
```

I put the errors in the code above using comments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using too many generic parameters.

Methods like `GetFieldValue<TModel, ...>` create a *second* `TModel` paramter which is not related to the first one.

In other words, they allow you to write

```
new RouteForm<PersonModel>().GetFieldValue<TruckModel, ...>()
```

This is obviously wrong.

Instead, just get rid of that parameter from each method and let them use the class' `TModel` parameter instead.

Comment: Done. This is was quite obvious once you pointed it out.
I can now write: new mvc.RouteForm<CurrentModel>(Html).hidden(m => m.Property);

Comment: Is there a way to get the compiler to infer the type from the constructor rather than explicitly passing it? Such as new mvc.RouteForm(Html).hidden(m => m.Property); Given the constructor:
public RouteForm(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)

Comment: @Nathaniel: No; type inference does not apply to constructors.  Instead, use an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the compilation error "ERRORS: TModel is TModel" is caused by declaring TModel twice in the generic declaration of hidden().

I haven't compiled this, but I'd try something like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static RouteForm<TModel> form(this HtmlHelper helper, TModel model)
    {
        return new RouteForm<TModel>(helper);
    }
}

public class RouteForm<TModel>
{
    public RouteForm<TModel> hidden(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
    }        
    public MvcHtmlString end()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you I was able to create a class that achieves the syntax I was looking for.

(the class is simplified for this post)
**class:**

```
public class RouteForm<TModel>
{
    public HtmlHelper<TModel> HtmlHelper { get; private set; }

    public RouteForm(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)
    {
        HtmlHelper = htmlHelper;
    }

    public RouteForm<TModel> hidden<TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        return this;
    }
    public MvcHtmlString end()
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
}
```

**extension method:**

```
public static RouteForm<TModel> form<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper)
{
     return new RouteForm<TModel>(helper);
}
```

**markup syntax:**

```
<%: Html
    .form()
        .hidden(m=>m.Property1)
        .hidden(m=>m.Property2)
    .end()
%>
```